# How to update my project with only changed files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

hi i am new to developing in asp net c # using visual studio 2019.
I am working on a project that will need updates. 
After completing the necessary updates, I use the publishing tool (FileZilla) and publish the site to the server.
How to update my project with only changed files? 
For example, if I only updated 5 files out of 100, you can only update these 5 files

Comment: I see you are new to StackOverflow. This question is very vague and does not convey that you have done thorough research into what you are trying to accomplish. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question to adhere to the StackOverflow standards.

Comment: Order files by modification dates?

Comment: I'm using felizila, but I would like to know if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a best practice to use FileZilla and deploy the changes manually but here's an idea:

1. After you set up the project. Install git and do a `git init`. That way you will set a new git repository. Git version control system which will help you find out changes on the files within the git repository (in your case the root folder).
2. When you are done with all the changes run the command `git status`. That way we will get all the changed files that have to be copied from the local machine (your) to the remote one via FileZilla.

More about git [here](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).

**Please note that using git in this case does not utilize its full potential.**

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @thiago if it helps you may want to upvote or accept the answer

Comment: I accepted, thanks for your help.
Sorry, I'm new to (Stack Overflow). I am still learning how to use the platform.